# Comparing a date between two date ranges i.e,.fromDate and toDate in java

Tags: java

How to check whether a given date is between two dates but it should not check with the time in given date.

I have tried with after but it checks for time range too.

Could anyone help me to know about this ?

TIA.,

Comment: **What** *did* you try? And a Java `Date` is just a number of milliseconds since an epoch (1/1/1970 00:00:00.000 UTC).

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The old date-time classes bundled with earlier versions of Java have been supplanted with the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 1 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 1 , 23 ) ;
```

To get the current date, specify a time zone. For any given moment, today’s date varies by time zone. For example, a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

We can use the `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and `isAfter` methods to compare. In date-time work we commonly use the Half-Open approach where the beginning of a span of time is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
Boolean containsToday = ( ! today.isBefore( start ) ) && ( today.isBefore( stop ) ) ;
```

### ThreeTen-Extra Project

The java.time framework can be extended by adding the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project’s jar to your project. In particular you may find the [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class handy.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the DateUtils.truncate from Apache Commons library.

Example:

```
DateUtils.truncate(new Date(), java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

Another option could be to use JODA-TIME which opens you the API for Local Date

Example:

```
DateTime first = ...;
DateTime second = ...;

LocalDate firstDate =       first.toLocalDate();
LocalDate secondDate = second.toLocalDate();
```

Then you could just compare both with JODA-TIME compareTo( ) or after () from the library :)